# How to solve "Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number" in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this:

```
> head(mydata, 24)
     time     exp2
1  Jan-99 24977.25
2  Feb-99 21186.07
3  Mar-99 41245.92
4  Apr-99    47.57
5  May-99 25254.42
6  Jun-99   164.95
7  Jul-99  9629.81
8  Aug-99   164.95
9  Sep-99 47091.12
10 Oct-99     0.09
11 Nov-99  3458.64
12 Dec-99    24.00
13 Jan-00 28636.17
14 Feb-00 23850.65
15 Mar-00 23680.16
16 Apr-00   513.82
17 May-00   252.17
18 Jun-00   178.10
19 Jul-00 20293.85
20 Aug-00   474.16
21 Sep-00   164.95
22 Oct-00   164.95
23 Nov-00   164.95
24 Dec-00    96.10
>
```

I would like to create a simple graph in ggplot, using:

```
newdata2 <- mydata %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(time, format = "%m/%y"))

ggplot(newdata2, aes(x = time, y = exp2)) +
      geom_line(color = "darkorchid4")
```

The error is:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust
the group aesthetic?
```

When running:

```
mydata$time <- as.Date(mydata$time, format = "%m/%y")
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = time, y = exp2)) +
      geom_line(color = "darkorchid4")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number
```

I can't understand why this error.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Did you check the output of `newdata2` ? What does `date` column consists?

Answer (score 1):

To connect the points set `group = 1` in your `aes`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = exp2, group = 1)) +
    geom_line(color = "darkorchid4")
```

---

If `time` is of class character then you need to convert it to a date object before you can change the format:

```
format(as.Date(paste0(df$time, "-01"), "%b-%y-%d"), "%m/%y")
[1] "01/99" "02/99" "03/99" "04/99" "05/99" "06/99" "07/99" "08/99" "09/99" "10/99" "11/99"
[12] "12/99" "01/00" "02/00" "03/00" "04/00" "05/00" "06/00" "07/00" "08/00" "09/00" "10/00"
[23] "11/00" "12/00"
```

Which can be used in your `mutate` function like:

```
df %>%
  mutate(date = format(as.Date(paste0(time, "-01"), "%b-%y-%d"), "%m/%y"))
```

---

**Update**

The above code will convert your values to a `character` object. Since you want to plot by and adjust the x-axis using `scale_x_date` then it needs to be a `Date` object. To give you an idea of what's possible here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste0(time, "-01"), "%b-%y-%d")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = exp2, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(color = "darkorchid4") + 
  geom_col(width = 2, fill = "red") + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 months",
               date_labels = "%b-%y") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(time = c("Jan-99", "Feb-99", "Mar-99", "Apr-99", 
"May-99", "Jun-99", "Jul-99", "Aug-99", "Sep-99", "Oct-99", "Nov-99", 
"Dec-99", "Jan-00", "Feb-00", "Mar-00", "Apr-00", "May-00", "Jun-00", 
"Jul-00", "Aug-00", "Sep-00", "Oct-00", "Nov-00", "Dec-00"), 
    exp2 = c(24977.25, 21186.07, 41245.92, 47.57, 25254.42, 164.95, 
    9629.81, 164.95, 47091.12, 0.09, 3458.64, 24, 28636.17, 23850.65, 
    23680.16, 513.82, 252.17, 178.1, 20293.85, 474.16, 164.95, 
    164.95, 164.95, 96.1)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it does not work. I've tried: ```newdata <- mydata %>%
mutate(date = format(as.Date(paste0(time, "-01"), "%b-%y-%d"), "%m/%y"))
``` and then ```ggplot(newdata2, aes(x = date, y = exp2, group=1)) +
      geom_line(color = "darkorchid4")``` but I got this error: ``` Error: `mapped_discrete` objects can only be created from numeric vectors
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.```

Comment: @Marian Can you provide more detail about how the time series in your post was created? The series you posted has values that 40000, but your graph does not. Perhaps there is some kind of moving average being plotted?

Comment: Well because the graph in Excel starts from Jan-2010... My issue that is very complicated to create a simple graph in R, using ggplot, when the date (time series are on monthly basis). For example ggplot works with no errors when my datetime column is only on yearly basis - but not with monthly data...

Comment: can we chat in a room?